# How does hazelcast deal with serialized lambdas?

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

According to Oracle its not advisable to serialize lamdbas, it's possible to use serialized lambdas with Hazelcast and I'm wondering how it deals with this, are there issues around duplication of lambda classes? e.g. the wrong code might be executed when generated classes for lambdas are duplicated. Im most interested in using the distributed executor and distributed map implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Serialized Lambdas are serialized according to the Java Lambda serialization specification. The only officially supported way is the standard way by doing the "double cast":

```
(Runnable & Serializable) (v) -> System.out.println(v);
```

That way it is serialized as with Java Serialization. However I would recommend not to capture any external content into the lambda.

Comment: What do you mean by external content, a lamda is just a function with no state, how could you store anything in it? Do you mean anonymous inner classes with state?

Comment: Nope the second you capture enclosing context, you have a lambda with state.